# Asp.net C#: Check if other threads are running in thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I'm making a thread that will trigger a change of files in App_GlobalResources, which again will cause the application to recompile, which will abort all other possible running threads.
I need to make this thread that will abort the other threads to wait until all other threads are not running. I have registered all threads in (Hashtable)Application["ThreadList"], but I don't seem to be able to access Application from Threads. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know ASP.NET doesn't abort currently running worker threads before it recompiles. It starts queuing up requests and waits for the existing requests to finish processing before it restarts AppDomain.

Update:

If your resources change daily than they shouldn't be hard-coded in resx files. Create a new resource provider that loads them from database or external files.

Comment: This is correct.  Basically, you don't need to worry about anything.  Asp.net will finish all current requests (which are run on threads) gracefully, then restart the app pool.

Comment: I keep getting an exception from threads running like "thread aborted" every time i change any files that causes the app to recompile.Why is that?

Comment: I can't imagine this is something that will happen very often (but could be wrong).... what I mean is: do you even need to worry about this? Also... messing with threads in ASP.NET (or at all) is not something for the faint hearted!

Comment: I need to rebuild some translation resource file every day, and these makes the app restart. The app has several threads that synchronizes  data from external servers, so running these at the same time will happen